# LCA algorithm in java (working with non binary trees)

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, lowest-common-ancestor

I have written a very simple tree class using arrays. This class needs to represent data that are linked together but they can have a different number of connections (i.e. one path could have only 3 nodes and another could have 10). Said that, I need to figure out one possible solution for performing LCA using this class with multiple leaf indexes.
this is the code that I have written so far:

```
public class ArrayTree {

/**
 * Tree structure
 */
private int[] t;

/**
 * The size of this database
 */
private int N;

/**
 * Creates an array tree with the given size
 * 
 * @param n
 *            the size of the array tree
 */
public ArrayTree(int n) {
    N = n;
    t = new int[N];
}

/**
 * add a new node
 */
public void addNode(int id, int parent) {
    validate(parent);
    t[id] = parent;
}


/**
 * Given an id this method will return an iterable object 
 * orderd from root to leaf
 */
public Iterable<Integer> getEntries(int id) {
    validate(id);
    List<Integer> entries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (id > 1) {
        entries.add(id);
        id = t[id];
        if (id == 0) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Reorder entries from root to leaf
    Collections.reverse(entries);
    return entries;
}

/**
 * Private method for validating indexes
 * 
 * @param index
 *            the index
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *             if index > N or index < 0
 */
private void validate(int index) {
    if (index >= N) {
        String error = String.format("Index: %d - Size: %d", index, N);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(error);
    } else if (index < 0) {
        String error = "negative index";
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(error);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,

Giovanni

Answer (score 2):

The basic LCA algorithm for multiple nodes does this:

- Get the depth of each node
- For each node with depth greater than the minimum depth, transition to the parent until all nodes are at the minimum depth
- while not all nodes are the same, transition each node to its parent
- When all the nodes converge to a single node, that's the LCA

I can't really provide code for this, since it's not obvious from your code how you recognize the root, which is necessary for finding the depth of a node.

Comment: So, if it is not possible to define a depth, it is not possible to search for LCA, right?

Comment: Well, yes, but if it's a tree then there is always a depth.  If you don't have it stored anywhere, then just count the number of links to the root

Comment: The thing here is that the number of links to the root is not the depth of my tree. I will explain it better below :)

My tree represent hierarchical values that have different depth. For example I could have something like this:
path1 = A -- C -- D -- F
path2 = A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
In these two situation is not trivial to get LCA as they are both F but they have different paths. Indeed, the two "C" coexist in my tree as two different nodes but they have the same meaning. 
I don't know if I was clear enough!

Comment: No, not clear.  What do you expect the answer to be in this case?  If you expect the answer to be "C", and the "C" nodes are different, then you are not looking for LCA.   If you expect the answer to be the A node, then no problem -- the depth of the first F is 3, the depth of the second F is 5, and the LCA is A

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You got it right, I think that it is not possible to do what I need with LCA as I expect the "F" in the case I showed you before.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find LCA for two leaf nodes ,call them **node1** and **node2**.

- Call `getEntries()` for node1
- Call `getEntries()` for node2
- Now traverse both list till the nodes on the both list are same
- The first node after which the next node in the list differs is the LCA.

This will work with non binary trees.